# Адрес элемента из указателя на вектор

Tags: c++

У меня есть указатель на вектор std::vector*. Как получить адрес элемента i этого вектора?

Comment: `p_vector->data() + i`

Comment: `&p_vector->at(i);`

Comment: Какой из способов лучше?

Comment: @solo, вот вам еще способ: `&(*p_vector)[i]`

Comment: @solo, способ с `at` чуть медленнее, но проверяет что `i` находится в допустимом диапазоне. Способы с `[]` и `data()` ничего не проверяют, за счет этого немного быстрее.

Comment: @freim что быстрее: ваш способ или способ VTT?

Comment: @solo, скорее всего без разницы. Или разница настолько ничтожная, что приборами не измерить. Используйте то, что вам больше нравится эстетически.

Comment: А как вы пробовали? Почему вообще возник вопрос? Чем получение адреса элемента из вектора отличается от каких-либо других объектов?